# What type of insulation should I use if my in-wall oven is heating the surrounding cabinets?

Tags: insulation, oven

We have an in-wall oven that is not properly insulated.  It heats up the surrounding cabinet.  The oven itself has internal insulation in good condition, but it is not strong enough to keep heat inside oven.  Is there some kind of outside wrap we can buy online that would fix this problem?  (we live in Chile, and the local manufacturer will not admit problem, so we need to fix it ourselves)

Comment: It's normal for some heat to leak to cabinets. Is the temperature high enough that you're worried about physical destruction of the cabinet material?

Answer (score 3):

I would **not** recommend additional insulating wrap for the unit itself, this could cause it to *overheat* and malfunction... or even catch on fire. You should be able to find the model and serial #s on a placard inside the door.   Check the manufacturer's minimum clearance requirements, if the cabinets are too close then you have the wrong oven or improperly constructed cabinets.

You may be able to add a layer of 1/4" drywall (or some other insulating layer) to the inside of the cabinet compartments, this would slow down the heat radiating from the unit to the cabinets. *But make sure manufacturer required minimum clearances are maintained.*

Comment: Hang on, now... there's a thermostat built-in to the oven that will cut the power when the temperature reaches the desired setting, right? Are ovens *really* designed so that they have to be able to lose heat out the sides, top and back?  Clearance requirements are a slightly different matter and may be the core of the issue here. Given the built-in insulation, the mfgr knows (presumably) how hot it's going to be right around the unit and how much clearance is required so that ignitable things like your *cabinets* don't get too hot. But I can't imagine more insulation harming the oven itself?

Comment: @Craig, the clearance requirements specified by the manufacturer, along with the external insulation (if any) are designed to allow the unit to perform safely and reliably. Many built-ins are designed to have free space for ventilation, some even have external cooling fans (like my GE Profile). The **external** components are not designed for extreme temps. If you wrap up the outside with some additional material, there is no knowing what might happen. Overheated wires? Overheated components? Short circuit causing fire? It's not about the cabinets catching fire, it's about the oven overheating

Comment: OK, I buy that. Thanks for the clarification!  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

My hob installation instructions calls for an insulation layer above the oven (which is below the hob). It fails to specify what or how thick etc. I'll probably use a bit of dry wall plasterboard  (pink stuff for around fires) and maybe a bit of silver heat proof tape.